# What is the fate of the engineering tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Given the discussion related to whether [Engineering questions are on topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site), we also need to consider whether the [engineering](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engineering) tag has any reason to exist. We discussed it in the chat room using the most recent questions, the transcript of which can be found at:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/discussion-of-the-engineering-tag

Should the [engineering](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engineering) tag exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think the [engineering](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engineering) should remain. It does not add information to the questions that are very important for answering/categorizing it. Additionally, the existing questions that are on-topic don't need the tag while the ones that would rely on the tag are off-topic based on our discussions about engineering.

Comment: I agree. A tag that is used only for bad questions is not a good tag at all. And this seems to largely be the case here.

Comment: Seeing no objections or downvotes, I suppose we can call this one decided.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to get this burninated.

Answer (score 2):

Done. The tag has been

[image: stupidest game I ever played]

And is now in the tag blacklist.