# Is it on-topic to ask about homemade construction of tools?

Tags: discussion, scope

As a mad scientist, skilled with his hands. I build my own tools, in many cases. I think would be very useful if can ask about contruction of tools related to the Physical (in general).

(contruction mean: procedures, materials, and other stuff)

I know the [FAQ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) say that "How to stabilize an unstable telescope?" is on-topic.

But what about "How to build a solar filter for my telescope?" Would that be on-topic? Or, "How to build a neutron source?" Would that be on-topic?

Comment: Are you really a *mad* scientist? Or are you just not really that happy right now?

Comment: @Jim and why does that matter?

Comment: So I know if I should tell you to cheer up or calm down

Comment: ah, maybe I made a bad translation of my intention.

Comment: No, it was good. I'm just being punny

Comment: im like Hydrogen but heavier.

Comment: How is the [mad grant proposal going](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=3445)?

Answer (score 11):

I'd (personally, not as a moderator) go with something like

> The design and construction of instruments that you can not easily buy---either because there is no commercial supply, because each one is necessarily unique or because you're jury-rigging a basic instrument for a home-experiment---might be on-topic. The design and construction of instruments that compete directly with commercially available instruments is off-topic as engineering.

Comment: that's my point, but much better explained.

Answer (score 5):

Others gave nice answers (with which personaly generaly agree), will add one more.

Questions having to do with application based on physical principles (or *practical physics*) should be on-topic. Even if these questions involve making things or measuring things or assessing things, etc..

This is just physics.

Now if one wants to build a telescope, the physical principles are what is relevant to build a working telescope. This involves the mathematical relations that are relevant to telescopes, the materials and their properties, the compensating factors for atmospheric effects, parallax calculations and all that.

If one wants to assess personaly the efficiency of an already made telescope (either home-made or purchased) using physical principles, this should also be on-topic.

Now if one wants the locations of the materials for making a telescope or extensive research about a specific material over another material for building a telescope. i would say this cannot be done correctly and effectively here. And this indeed involves engineering research which can be extensive.

Nevertheless the physical principles remain the same, even for assessing the various materials, but any furher investigation would be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is more an engineering question, which in general is off-topic; see this topic: [Are engineering questions appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site).

There is currently no general engineering SE site, but there is one in commitment phase: [Area 51 - Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering?referrer=KcfjUC9wdeJUZvrx04eTvg2). So I'd suggest you wait until it matures or even commit to the proposed site yourself.

Comment: Thanks bringing this up! It was news to me that a venue for engineering questions was in the works.
Usually when a question is deemed to be "engineering", the poster is just SOL. We could at least let them know that Area 51 exists. 
Also since there isn't an fully established site yet, it wouldn't be the end of the world to be a wee bit more tolerant of questions on the engineering/experimental physics borderline.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not going to say there isn't a way of asking those questions that would be on-topic. With the right wording, you *could* manage to get away with asking them. But it's risky business. Engineering questions are generally off-topic here and asking how to build tools for science is definitely more of an engineering topic. My advice would be to avoid the trouble and not ask them, but if you think you can make the questions enough about physics and less about how to build something, then try your luck and we'll see what the reviewers think.

Comment: *...hot to build tools for science is definitely more of an engineering topic.* [I'm not so sure about that](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6135).

Comment: @KyleKanos what part of that says asking about building the tools is experimental physics?

Comment: The tags [tag:experimental-physics] and [tag:experimental-technology]

Comment: Do questions on "how to build the tools for an experiment" pertain to the limits, management, or operation of the scientific equipment? Do they ask about the design, process, data, or analysis of the experiment?

Comment: how to build the tools is not usually about the limits of them or about using them. It is also not at all about the experiment itself

Comment: I would contend that they could be asked in such a way to satisfy that.

Comment: But, I did point out that the question could be worded in an on-topic way. I merely said that usually, these are more engineering issues

Comment: But you state that it's ***definitely** more of an engineering topic* (emphasis mine) and I'm not sure that I agree with that.

Comment: 51% engineering and 49% experimental physics is definitely more of an engineering topic