# Would it be useful to link the engineering SE on closed engineering questions or not?

Tags: discussion

On some SE sites, it is normal that the closing reasons contain also a link to another SE site, where the question could have a better chance to survive:

[image]

On other SE sites, it is unthinkable and even suggesting this results around -20 on the meta.

P.s. this question is *not* a duplicate of [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6501/should-the-engineering-close-vote-be-changed-in-light-of-the-new-engineering-se): that post is asking a *migration path* to the Engineering SE, while I am questioning about the advantages/disadvantages of a *link to the Engineering SE in the close reason*.

Comment: To be fair, the existing close reason does already link to a [meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4536/) that contains a 'where can I ask it?' that links to both E.SE and EE.SE. A two-click pathway can well be a reasonable trade-off for a broader array of site link targets.

Comment: Something worth noting is that a lot of the engineering questions here wouldn't be ok on Engineering SE. They frequently resemble "construct/design this for me now", which isn't OK there. We need to be careful that we don't give users this impression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Would it be useful to link the engineering SE on closed engineering questions or not?

Yes, obviously.

---

That said, I want to remind everyone that applied physics has a lot of overlap with what you (particularly theorists) think of as "engineering". If someone posts here asking about lab equipment etc. please do not jump for the "off topic" close reason.

We've [talked about this before](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/experimental-physics-engineering) and I gave a [well received opinion on how to think about engineering-ish posts on our site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/experimental-physics-engineering/6136#6136).

Comment: One difficulty is that there are at least two engineering sites ([electronics.se] and [engineering.se]).

Comment: @dmckee My impression is that the Engineering SE is much more common.