# How to change the close reasons about offtopic engineering posts to contain the link to the Engineering SE?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

On this [meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/would-it-be-useful-to-link-the-engineering-se-on-closed-engineering-questions-or), we have a consensus that it would be useful to link to the Engineering SE on closed engineering questions.

It requires a proper wording approved by the community.

The current wording is this:

> This question appears to be about engineering, which is the
>   application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a
>   specific problem. As such, it is off topic for this site, which deals
>   with the science, whether theoretical or experimental, of how the
>   natural world works. For more information, see this [meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4536/).

Related material:

(from @DanielSank 's [reply](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9050/32426))

> We've [talked about this
>   before](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/experimental-physics-engineering)
>   and I gave a [well received opinion on how to think about
>   engineering-ish posts on our
>   site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/experimental-physics-engineering/6136#6136).

Comment: The maximal size of a close reason can be at most 500 characters. The current close reason is 379 characters long. The source size counts.

Comment: To repeat the comment that I left the answer you linked, one difficulty is that there are at least two engineering sites ([electronics.se] and [engineering.se]).

Comment: [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/668651/last-100-as-offtopic-closed-questions) to the last 100, as offtopic closed questions (the SEDE was synchronized last sunday). Unfortunately, the SEDE doesn't contain information about the reason of the offtopic closure.

Comment: @dmckee The SEDE query in the previous post shows relative clearly that it the Engineering SE has the majority. Furthermore, also the consensus in the previous [meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/would-it-be-useful-to-link-the-engineering-se-on-closed-engineering-questions-or) is about the Engineering SE, and not from the others.

Comment: Without knowing the migration rate (accept vs all, reject vs all), is this really necessary? Wouldn't it be easier to add the relevant links to the linked Meta page?

Comment: @KyleKanos We have already a [consensus](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/would-it-be-useful-to-link-the-engineering-se-on-closed-engineering-questions-or) that it is necessary, and we have also a consensus that it is needed to the Engineering SE.

Comment: Since Jan 1, we've had a grand total of one question migrated to Engineering. Completely worthless endeavor, IMO. Maybe EE would be better suited, but most of those ~30 migrations have been rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a proposed wording for the new close reason:

> This question appears to be about engineering, which is the application of scientific knowledge to solve a specific problem. As such, it is off topic for this site, which deals with the science, whether theoretical or experimental, of how the natural world works. For more information, see this [meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4536/). Your question may be on topic on the [Q&A site for professionals and students of engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It is the current wording, extended with a single sentence. To fit the 500 character limit, I removed some words from the middle of the second sentence. The name of the Engineering SE is from the [list of all SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest).

Comment: I'd replace "on the Q&A site..." at the end with just "Engineering Stack Exchange" (with a link).