# Is this a good question? - How come Land Speed Records for Cars get higher speeds than motorcycles? (Even though they're less aerodynamic?)

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Is this a good question?

> How come Land Speed Records for Cars get higher speeds than motorcycles? (Even though they're less aerodynamic?) Is it because more rocket can be packed onto a car, as compared to a motorbike?

Posted, and flagged for a move to Engineering: [What are the biggest reasons that Cars get higher Land Speed Records than motorcycles'?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201819/what-are-the-biggest-reasons-that-land-speed-records-for-cars-are-than-motorcycl)

Comment: Sorry. you posted on Physics *even though you believe it doesn't belong here*?!? Why?

Comment: @dmckee - Wasn't really thinking... Apparently...

Answer (score 1):

Such a question would probably fall afoul of our [engineering policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site). There are many, many factors to consider, a number of which are simply not physics. In fact you've already covered the physics -- the aerodynamics. Factors such as difficulty of construction and human safety (do *you* want to be going at supersonic speeds with just a leather jacket protecting you?) would be needed to answer the question.

Comment: So... Move to Engineering.Meta? If you think so, go ahead and flag...

Comment: @Qmechanic - Do you agree with Chris? If you do, could you move this to Engineering.meta?

Comment: *"do you want to be going at supersonic speeds with just a leather jacket protecting you?"* If you haven't seen *The World's Fastest Indian* you might like it. About a guy who set a land speed record for small displacement motorcycles. And yeah, I'm too chicken.

Comment: Just to help close out an older meta thread.  The land speed record question [was migrated to Engineering](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4115/what-are-the-biggest-reasons-that-cars-get-higher-land-speed-records-than-motorc) but is too broad of a question for the Engineering site.  It was closed on Engineering and the migration was rejected which sent the question back to Physics.