# Stop [efficient-energy-use] tag!

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [efficient-energy-use](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficient-energy-use) seems to be rather ill-defined. The tag wiki excerpt states:

> Use the tag *Efficient Energy Use* in questions having to do with processes or engines or constructions where energy is spent or transfered and the efficiency thereof. Efficiency means both the measurement and the techniques and principles for its optimization.

This does not seem to be a useful tag. What "process or engine or construction" *doesn't* transfer energy in some way? Optimizing a given "process or engine or construction" is not physics, it is engineering, and hence [off-topic here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4535/50583). Measuring the efficiency of some "process or engine or construction" seems *very* specific and doesn't deserve its own tag, in my opinion - tagging questions about the measurement of energy efficiency with [energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy) seems perfectly sufficient.

I therefore propose the tag be removed.

Comment: The tag description is not good, but the set of questions with that tag share a common theme that matches the tag name. Why not *fix* it instead of deleting?

Comment: @DanielSank: If you have a fix in mind, you could add it as an answer here - the purpose of this meta question is to determine what should be done with the tag. If I was totally sure it is unsalvagable, I would have just gone ahead and removed it from the questions so it would be auto-deleted.

Comment: In some cases the tag seems to be used when something like [thermodynamic-efficiency] should be used instead; possible because we don't have the right tag. Subquestion: how many of the questions using [efficient-energy-use] that *shouldn't* use [thermodynamic-efficiency] instead are any good? There seems to be a lot of junk in that tag.

Comment: @DanielSank Well, there are a lot of themes that fit that description that would nevertheless not be good tags here. Like "eyes" or "eulers-method" or "bungee-jumping". So I don't think that's a useful criterion.

Comment: @DavidZ It seems like a perfectly good criterion in addition to the orthogonal criterion that questions should be high quality. Some of the questions with the energy efficiency tag are perfectly fine IMHO. dmckee makes a good point about using [thermodynamic-efficiency] although I worry about laypersons not knowing to use it. "Energy" is a more common word.