# The on-topic page in the help center does not mention engineering

Tags: discussion, scope

It recently came up in a meta post that OP had checked out the [on-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in the help center, and could not see anything about engineering. That does seem to be the case, and although the tour mentions engineering, I do think it is something important enough to merit a place in the on-topic page (we even have a close reason for that!). Is there a particular reason why we don't mention this? If not, can we add a brief section? A rephrased version of the close reason (just a couple of phrasing corrections) should suffice, in my opinion.

This is the close reason:

> This question appears to be about engineering, which is the application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem. As such, it is off topic for this site, which deals with the science, whether theoretical or experimental, of how the natural world works. For more information, see [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4536).

An appropriate version for the on-topic page would be under the section "Some kinds of questions should not be asked here:", and would read like:

> - **Engineering questions:**
>
>   Questions about engineering, which is the application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem, are generally considered to be off-topic for this site, which deals with the science, whether theoretical or experimental, of how the natural world works. For more information, see [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4536).

Comment: This section is almost certainly under space constraints, which might or might not allow for this addition. It'd be good if a mod or a CM could chime in with what the status is.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Well, we have two bullet points about off-topic stuff which don't have their own close reasons. I think engineering is an important enough point to replace those, if it comes to that.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The limit is 30,000 characters i.e. same as [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176447). That page certainly has a lot less than 30,000 characters currently.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what "phrasing corrections" do you have in mind?

Comment: @KyleKanos Only trivial ones which are needed for the different context. The close reason (without the links) is "This question appears to be about engineering, which is the application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem. As such, it is off topic for this site, which deals with the science, whether theoretical or experimental, of how the natural world works. For more information, see this meta post."

Comment: The thing in the on-topic page would need to be under the section "Some kinds of questions should not be asked here:", and would read "**Engineering questions**:\\Questions about engineering, which is the application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem, are generally considered to be off-topic for this site, which... _[same as close reason, with links in the format as the other entries in that page]_"

Comment: Okay, I figured that was the case, but wasn't sure if you thought there was some grammatical fixes needed in the close reason

Comment: I've edited the question to include the suggested changes to the close reason which would be needed for the on-topic page.

Comment: Oh, and while we're examining that page, there's some inconsistent usage of "Physics - Stack Exchange" and "Physics Stack Exchange"